# mod_pagespeed removes external (third party cdn) js resources

Tags: javascript, mod-pagespeed

I'm wondering why? is it a requirement of pagespeed to store all javascript locally?

I found this in my pagespeed.conf

```
# ModPagespeedDomain
# authorizes rewriting of JS, CSS, and Image files found in this
# domain. By default only resources with the same origin as the
# HTML file are rewritten.
```

However, this doesn't seem to be the case when external js files are just chucked off the DOM.

**EDIT**

Ok, so with the default settings third party js resources located in the head section. ex:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.10/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

is removed from the source code with pagespeed. So i did a bit of digging and fooled around with different settings. And what i came up with is that it seems that the following filtes causes the issue:

```
combine_css
inline_css
```

What i did was that i enabled one filter at a time until i got the "error".

This has to be a bug? doesn't it?

Comment: Are you using the "leave off the protocol" trick I mentioned in my answer?

Comment: Submitted bug report. http://code.google.com/p/modpagespeed/issues/detail?id=292

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 4 problems here that are contriving to break this example:

1. You claim the doc is XHTML via DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 ...
2. You don't close the link-tags on lines 9-12 (see attachment of
   Issue 292 -- link below)
3. mod_pagespeed 0.9.16.9 believed the XHTML tag implies balanced tags
4. mod_pagespeed should be more pessimistic in the presence of unbalanced tags.

Fixing any one of these 4 problems will resolve this.  Problems 3 & 4 are fixed in 0.9.17.3, which is available in source-code form but not yet as a binary.  We're in the process of releasing this.

This issue is also reported as http://code.google.com/p/modpagespeed/issues/detail?id=292 which is really a duplicate of http://code.google.com/p/modpagespeed/issues/detail?id=252

Comment: Ah, didn't notice the unbalanced tags. Ill test it out! Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

No, `mod_pagespeed` doesn't require that you only use local JavaScript resources.

If your CDN links use the nifty ["leave off the protocol" trick](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/skipping-protocol.html), it may be worth looking to see if that's confusing `mod_pagespeed`.

If not, take a look at your `pagespeed.conf` (or wherever you're keeping your pagespeed config options). It sounds like something is mis-configured. [Configuration options are listed here](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/config_filters.html). There are a couple related to JavaScript, including `combine_javascript` and `inline_javascript`. I wouldn't expect either of those to relate to files being loaded from CDNs, but it may be worth taking a look. (Sadly the documentation page for the [`combine_javascript` option](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/filter-js-combine.html) is messed up right now, it's an exact copy of the page for the [`combine_css` option](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/filter-css-combine.html). I've [reported that as a bug](https://code.google.com/p/modpagespeed/issues/detail?id=290).)